# How to invoke Property/Field of Generic Type with Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, static

Consider Following class

```
class A<T> where T:new()
{
  public static T Instance = new T();
  A()
  {
  }
}
```

I have 2 questions

1. I need `Instance` object with Reflection.  I have tried following

   ```
   var type = typeof(A<int>);  
   // var type = typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int)); // Also tried this

   var instanceMember1 = type.GetMember("Instance",  BindingFlags.Static );  // returns null
   var instanceMember2 = type.GetField("Instance",  BindingFlags.Static ); // returns null
   ```

   I have also tried to Change `Instance` to property and call `GetProperty` with no success.
2. After removing `new()` constraint and making `constructor` private, How to invoke private (parameterless) constructor through reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `BindingFlags.Public` to your flags for `GetField`.

```
var instanceMember1 = type.GetField("Instance", BindingFlags.Static |
    BindingFlags.Public);
```

To invoke the private constructor:

```
var ctor = type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
    null, Type.EmptyTypes, new ParameterModifier[0]);
var instance = ctor.Invoke(null) as A<int>;
```